# Бэкап MS SQL 2008 R2 на dvd

Tags: резервное-копирование, sql-server

Здравствуйте.
Как реализовать ежедневный автоматический бэкап базы данных на dvd-rw. Предполагается использовать один dvd-rw диск в течение недели, потом менять его на новый. Интересуют бесплатные утилиты.

**Добавлено.**

Более подробно. Объект - кафе (работает 24 часа). Есть сервер на нем работает программный комплекс Tillypad, который в свою очередь работает с базой данных. В 3 часа делается перерыв. Написан скрипт, который останавливает сервер приложений Tillypad (так как иначе бэкап базы не возможен). После бэкапа базы запускается сервер приложений, потом делается бэкап всего диска в зеркало. Плюсом к этому нужно реализовать резервное копирование *.bak файла на dvd-rw диск.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Можно организовать бэкап SQL Server R2 (в том числе и в редакции Express) без сторонних утилит.

Создать скрипт сохранения с помощью [Transact-SQL](http://msdn.microsoft.com/ru-ru/library/ms186865(v=SQL.105).aspx):

```
BACKUP DATABASE database TO DISK='C:\database.bak';
```

Создать пакетный скрипт-обертку с помощью [sqlcmd](http://msdn.microsoft.com/ru-ru/library/ms162773.aspx):

```
sqlcmd -i C:\backup.sql -o C:\backup.log
```

И поставить скрипт на периодическое исполнение, например, с помощью [Task Scheduler](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa383614(v=vs.85).aspx).

**Дополнено.**

Как копировать на DVD-RW без вспомогательных программ? Нужно отформатировать диск, так чтобы была возможность дозаписи ("Живой формат"). Тогда для сохранения бэкапа потребуется всего одна команда (например, для DVD-RW диска E:):

```
copy C:\backup.sql E:\
```

Comment: Резервное копирование на другой логический диск у меня и так идет штатными средствами. Мне нужно, чтобы после копирования стандартными средствами sql этот файл *.bak писался на dvd-rw, без постороннего вмешательства в течение недели (в случае, если на диске нет места, то перезаписывать более ранний архив).

Comment: @Иваныч Надо отформатировать DWD-RW диск для дозаписи и можно будет писать на него командами copy, move и т.п.

Comment: @userx, видимо я плохо объяснил изначально. Если знаете подскажите программу или скрипт, чтобы форматировать dvd-rw для дозаписи (моя проблема заключается именно в этом). Заранее спасибо.

Answer (score 0):

Попробуйте написать CLR-процедуру, которая будет включена в задачу, выполняемую по расписанию. А уже в ней писать на DVD средствами .NET.

Comment: Что-то довольно сложно. На сколько я знаю, Windows имеет свои функции для записи DVD-CD - дисков. Может, можно сохранять резервные копии БД во временных папках, которые Windows использует для записи данных на диски. Затем исполнять какой-нибудь скрипт, начинающий запись (скорее перезапись) на диск.
Но вот дело в том, что на моем жизненном опыте довольно часто попадались некачественные записывания на диск, которые потом невозможно было нигде прочитать. Может, лучше всего отказаться от записи на DVD???